# Is there a way to write a pandas SQL query across multiple lines with comments?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

When writing a regular expression, it is possible to write the expression across multiple lines and including annotation, then compile the expression using the `re.VERBOSE` option before passing the compiled version. I'd like to do something similar with a `pandas.read_sql_query`.

For example, instead of:

```
result = pd.read_sql_query('select a.gvkey, a.tic, a.datadate as fyearend, year(a.datadate) as year, month(a.datadate) as fyrc, b.datadate, month(b.datadate) as month, b.trt1m from COMPM.FUNDA a join COMPM.SECM b on a.gvkey = b.gvkey and year(a.datadate) = year(b.datadate) where a.TIC = "IBM" and a.datafmt = "STD" and a.consol="C" and a.indfmt = "INDL" and year(a.datadate)>1980', engine)
```

I would like to write something like:

```
q = """select a.gvkey, 
    a.tic,                      #COMMENTS
    a.datadate as fyearend,     #COMMENTS
    year(a.datadate) as year,   #COMMENTS
    month(a.datadate) as fyrc, b.datadate, 
    month(b.datadate) as month, 
    b.trt1m 
    from COMPM.FUNDA a join COMPM.SECM b on a.gvkey = b.gvkey and year(a.datadate) = year(b.datadate) 
    where a.TIC = "IBM" 
        and a.datafmt = "STD" 
        and a.consol="C" 
        and a.indfmt = "INDL" 
        and year(a.datadate)>1980
"""

result = p.read_sql_query(q ,engine)
```

My question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33944522/is-it-possible-to-split-a-sequence-of-pandas-commands-across-multiple-lines) question about splitting python commands across multiple lines, but I'd like to add comments inside the query.

As I mentioned, what I'd like to do in the pandas/SQL case is similar to what can be done in the regular expression case with `re.VERBOSE`. Here is an example with regex:

```
pattern = r'''\s(shares?| #COMMENTS
            warrants?|       #COMMENTS
            stock|           #AND SO ON...
            (non)?vest(ed)?
            )\b             
            '''
crit = re.compile(pattern_nopt, re.VERBOSE)
match=re.search(crit, string)
```

This would make the query more readable and I find it important to annotate queries exhaustively when sharing code with coauthors.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes it will works but you have to use the right [comment delimiter for SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_comment.html) :
  `--` for an inline comment
  `/* foo.. */` (as in C) for a multi-lines comment

So it will looks like :

```
q = """select a.gvkey, 
    a.tic,                      -- COMMENTS
    a.datadate as fyearend,     -- COMMENTS
    year(a.datadate) as year,   /* Another very long
    and multi-lines comment... */
    month(a.datadate) as fyrc, b.datadate, 
    month(b.datadate) as month, 
    b.trt1m from COMPM.FUNDA a join COMPM.SECM b on a.gvkey = b.gvkey and year(a.datadate) = year(b.datadate) 
    where a.TIC = "IBM" 
        and a.datafmt = "STD" 
        and a.consol="C" 
        and a.indfmt = "INDL" 
        and year(a.datadate)>1980
"""

result = p.read_sql_query(q, conn)
```

Comment: mgc, Thanks! This works when I use multi-line comment(`/* foo */`) , but not when I use the inline comment (`--`). Do you have any thoughts on why that might be?

Comment: @ArthurMorris you're welcome! I don't really know, I tested (successfully) with the inline delimiter fisrt. Are you sure that the comment started by `--` ends by a end-of-line ? Or do you have any error message ?

Comment: The comment seems to end with a new line, but I maybe wrong. The error I get is: `Syntax error, expecting one of the following:  ;, !, !!, &, (, *, **, +, -, '.', /, <, <=, <>, =, >, >=, AND, EQ, EQT, EXCEPT, GE, GET, GROUP, GT, GTT, HAVING, INTERSECT, LE, LET, LT, LTT -2147295222 ERROR 22-322`

Comment: thanks again for the answer! I'll debug further myself.

Comment: It turns out that my problem is due to the fact that the database I'm querying uses SAS SQL so the `--` comments are not recognized as comments. I guess the lesson is that the comment format within the SQL query is determined by the system that is processing the query and not by Python.

Comment: I guess you're right, I tested my answer with pandas, using a `connection` object from `sqlite3` module (that's also why I have put a link to SQLite doc as you mentioned it), but other db manager may have different behaviors (anyway i think that `--` is the reference symbol for comments in SQL specifications)

Comment: Once I have enough reputation I'll give you an upvote!