# When using read_sql_query in pandas, how to write the SQL across multiple lines?

Tags: python, pandas

my question is pretty much what it sounds like: Is it possible to write my SQL across multiple lines for ease of reading when using the read_sql_query method please? For example, to make this:

```
v_df = pd.read_sql_query(
    sql = "SELECT EVENT_INVITE, COUNT(ACCOUNT_NUMBER) AS CUSTOMERS FROM CS.SM_MAR22_FINAL GROUP BY EVENT_INVITE ORDER BY EVENT_INVITE;",
    con = v_conn)
```

Look something more like this:

```
v_df = pd.read_sql_query(
    sql = " SELECT EVENT_INVITE, COUNT(ACCOUNT_NUMBER) AS CUSTOMERS 
            FROM CS.SM_MAR22_FINAL 
            GROUP BY EVENT_INVITE 
            ORDER BY EVENT_INVITE
            ;",
    con = v_conn)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: use python multiline strings `""" SELECT ... ; """` with triple quotes.

Comment: This is basic Python syntax, it has nothing to do with pandas.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pythonic way to create a long multi-line string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660435/pythonic-way-to-create-a-long-multi-line-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

python multiline string is your best bet here.
So in your case:

```
v_df = pd.read_sql_query(
    sql = """
          SELECT EVENT_INVITE, COUNT(ACCOUNT_NUMBER) AS CUSTOMERS 
          FROM CS.SM_MAR22_FINAL 
          GROUP BY EVENT_INVITE 
          ORDER BY EVENT_INVITE
          ;""",
    con = v_conn)
```

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138740/is-there-a-way-to-write-a-pandas-sql-query-across-multiple-lines-with-comments) adds some details about formatting and comments